# POST http://localhost:3000/product 500 (Internal Server Error) AngulaJS, Express, Node y Postgres

Tags: angularjs, nodejs, postgresql, express

necesito ayuda para resolver lo siguiente, estoy haciendo la conexión a la BD, cuando hago un GET me funciona muy bien, pero cuando hago un post, me arroja este error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/product 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
// app.use(logger(app.get("env") === "production" ? "combined" : "dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status( err.code || 500 )
    .json({
      status: 'error',
      message: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500)
  .json({
    status: 'error',
    message: err.message
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pg = require('pg');
const path = require('path');
const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://localhost:5432/todo';

let db = require('../queries');
// POSTGRES QUERIES
router.post('/api/product', db.postProduct);


module.exports = router;
```

queries.js

```
var promise = require('bluebird');

var options = {
  // Initialization Options
  promiseLib: promise
};

var pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);
var connectionString = 'postgres://localhost:5432/todo';
var db = pgp(connectionString);

// QUERY FUNCTIONS
function postProduct(req, res, next) {
  // var pupID = parseInt(req.params.id);
  let producto = req.body.producto;
  let descripcion = req.body.desc;
  let precio = req.body.precio;
  let proveedor = req.body.proveedor;
  let cantidad = req.body.cant;
  let tipo = req.body.tipo;
  let fecha_registro = new Date();

  console.log(producto);
  console.log(desc);
  res.end();

  db.oneOrNone('INSERT INTO productos (producto, descripcion, precio, proveedor, cantidad, tipo, fecha) VALUES (${producto}, ${descripcion}, ${precio}, ${proveedor}, ${cantidad}, ${tipo}, ${fecha_registro})', {
    producto: producto
    , descripcion: descripcion
    , precio: precio
    , proveedor: proveedor
    , cantidad: cantidad
    , tipo: tipo
    , fecha_registro: fecha_registro
  })
    .then(function (data) {
      res.status(200)
      .json({
        data:data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return next(error);
      console.log("ERROR: ", error);
    });
}

module.exports = {
  postProduct: postProduct
};
```

app.js (angularjs)

```
angular.module('nodeTodo', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('mainController', ($scope, $http) => {

})

// ENRUTAMIENTO DINAMICO
.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
   .when('/' ,{templateUrl: './inicio.html', controller: 'IndexCtrl'})
   .when('/newProduct' ,{templateUrl: './newproduct.html', controller: 'newproductCtrl'})
   .when('/almacen' ,{templateUrl: './almacen.html', controller: 'almacenCtrl'})
   .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
})


.controller('almacenCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window){

})

.controller('newproductCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.create = function(){
    $http.post('/product')
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log("OK");
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + response);
    })
  }
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="nodeTodo">
 <head>
   <title>Bienvenido</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css">
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="mainController">

<!--NAVEGATION MENU-->
 <div class="navbar">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Inicio</a>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active">
         <a href="/#vista1">Vista 1</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="/#vista2">Vista 2</a>
       </li>
     </ul>    
   </div>
 </div>
<!-- FIN NAVEGATION MENU -->

<!--SHOW PAGES-->

  <div class="container">
   <div ng-view></div>
<!--     <ul ng-repeat="todo in todoData">
      <li ng-repeat="i in todo">{{ i.name }}</li>
      <li ng-repeat="i in todo">{{ i.age }}</li>
    </ul> -->
  </div>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

newproduct.html

```
  <form class="form-horizontal"> 
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="producto">Producto:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="producto" placeholder="Nombre del producto" name="producto" ng-model="producto">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="tipo">Tipo:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tipo" placeholder="ejemplo: unidades, kilos, fracos, bolsas, etc." name="tipo">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="descripcion">Descripción:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" placeholder="Descripción del producto" name="desc" ng-model="desc">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="precio">Precio:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="precio" placeholder="Precio del producto" name="precio">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="cant">Cantidad:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cant" placeholder="Cantidad de productos" name="cant">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pro">Proveedor:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="proveedor" placeholder="Nombre del proveedor" name="proveedor">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Guardar" ng-click="create()">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Así es como tengo los archivos, espero me puedan ayudar en que estoy haciendo mal, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: yo cambiaría `router.post('/api/product', db.postProduct);` por `app.post('/api/product', db.postProduct);` a ver q sale

Comment: Hola @aloMalbarez ya lo había hecho, pero no me sigue arrojando el mismo error...

Comment: tiro de suerte a ver si arranca : `router.route('/api/product').post(db.postProduct);`